# ASWebAuthenticationSession (Google-sign-in IOS) build real device not running

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I do google sign in but error, I have check lib google use ASWebAuthenticationSession but real device not working, simulator working, Here is my code
import AuthenticationServices
import Firebase
class TestMVSocialNetworkLinkVC: UIViewController {
var authenticationVC: ASWebAuthenticationSession?
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
self.view.backgroundColor = .red
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

```
@IBAction func signinGoogle(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let url = URL.init(string: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?state=g_EVxzV9aI9dF168dpW4NIGdXZ6V0_ODG6LZzK7TnrE&gpsdk=gid-7.0.0&response_type=code&nonce=Gsyssstx6Yi_fcstlg3l_LVRxaovtg5LF2qqXQbvap8&code_challenge_method=S256&emm_support=1&gidenv=ios&scope=email%20profile&code_challenge=Bcm2LsD7iXpvb9syC2hbsTrVGuoPQHJNDdKHuQIQrdg&redirect_uri=com.googleusercontent.apps.909227097874-hb97j1bb3mlto9ilpc1hmog2dopp1mvm:/oauth2callback&device_os=iOS%2015.6.1&client_id=909227097874-hb97j1bb3mlto9ilpc1hmog2dopp1mvm.apps.googleusercontent.com&include_granted_scopes=true") else { return  }
    let callbackScheme = "com.googleusercontent.apps.909227097874-hb97j1bb3mlto9ilpc1hmog2dopp1mvm"

    authenticationVC = ASWebAuthenticationSession(url: url, callbackURLScheme: callbackScheme, completionHandler: { (callbackURL, error) in

    })
    authenticationVC?.presentationContextProvider = self
    authenticationVC?.prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession = false
        self.authenticationVC?.start()
```

//        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: GIDConfiguration.init(clientID: "909227097874-hb97j1bb3mlto9ilpc1hmog2dopp1mvm.apps.googleusercontent.com"), presenting: self)
}

}
extension TestMVSocialNetworkLinkVC: ASWebAuthenticationPresentationContextProviding {
func presentationAnchor(for session: ASWebAuthenticationSession) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
return self.view.window!
}
}

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRF9r.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLPol.jpg)